# Kendo DropDownList server filtering with others parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

I have a Kendo Dropdown List

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
              .Name("component")

              .DataTextField("Text")
              .DataValueField("Value")
              .Filter("contains")
              .DataSource(source =>
              {
                  source.Read(read =>
                  {
                      read.Action("GetListComponent_DataSource", "Steps")
                          .Data("StepsObj.getComponentFilters(param1,param2)");
                  })
                  .ServerFiltering(true);
              })
              .Enable(true)
              .AutoBind(false)
    )
```

I need to filter this dropdown based on what the user search and on others 2 parameters that i send to the method

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetListComponent_DataSource(Guid param1,Guid param2, string text)
    {
        var stuff= await GetTheStuffAsync(param1,param2,text);
        return Json(stuff, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The Problem is the the text is always null and so the filter doesn't work. If I remove the others parameters then the filter work.

Any suggestion on how to resolve it?

Comment: In the above code, there is no premise of passing `text` as a parameter, only `param1, param2`

Comment: What is the code for function `StepsObj.getComponentFilters()`?

Comment: @Richard My guess is that it's simply a javascript function that returns the two `param` 's however I'm unsure where the string test is coming from